# Numerical find and replace issue

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column with a list of stings as below

```
"Plate 2 Day 2 - 220304_Plate-2_Day-2-Well-number-001_Processed_PrintToExcel.xlsx"
```

Well numbers go from 1-56 and Day and plates change as well - there is thousands of entries in this dataset.

I want to change the well numbers from 002 - 009, 003-017, 004-0025, 005-33, 006-41 and so on.

If I use

```
   df_find_replace <- df %>% mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1,pattern = "002", replacement = "009"))
```

when I go to change well 009 to 018

```
df_find_replace <- df %>% mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1,pattern = "009", replacement = "018"))
```

I'll end up changing the well that was 002 to 018.

If this code accepted a pipe I should be able to avoid this? As each finds a replace would be working on the original df?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are tying to do. What is the logic for changing numbers? Do you have a fixed set of replacements? Are you only trying to change the number after "Well-number-" and leave all the other ones along? It would maybe be helpful to have a few more lines of sample input and then the desired result of that sample input so possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: It sounds like yes, if you source from `df`, process, then write to `df2`, data in `df` is unchanged by processing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic for the changes (you didn't answer @MrFlick's questions), but this should get you started:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(col1 = "Plate 2 Day 2 - 220304_Plate-2_Day-2-Well-number-001_Processed_PrintToExcel.xlsx")

df %>% 
    extract(col1, 
            into = c("plate_no", "day_no", "rest"),
            regex = "^Plate (\\d+) Day (\\d+) - (.*)") %>% 
    mutate(plate_no = case_when(plate_no == "2" ~ "009",
                                plate_no == "9" ~ "018")) %>%
    mutate(new_col1 = paste0("Plate ", plate_no, " Day ", day_no, " - ", rest))
```

Use a regular expression (regex) to split the string into multiple columns.  Then do your changes.  Whatever logic you use, do it here and it won't overwrite itself.  Then, paste everything back together again.  If you want help writing the regex, then you'll need to specify the logic you want.